# How to differentiate Twitter replies from initial Tweet thread

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I built a simple script that uses the Tweepy API to download Tweets from a given profile.

It all works fine and dandy, but I do not want to download replies to Tweets; I'd like to only download the initial tweet.

Say I follow profile X.
X posts something. Then Y replies. Then X replies again. I'd like to discard both Y's and X's replies and only keep X's original post.

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html?highlight=replies#hide-replies

Comment: See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - what code have you tried, and what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Twitter API v1.1, you can use [`API.user_timeline`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/api.html#tweepy.API.user_timeline)'s `exclude_replies` paramter.
With Twitter API v2, you can use [`Client.get_users_tweets`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_tweets)'s`exclude` parameter.

Comment: thanks for the tip, it worked out perfectly. I'm on API v1.1